# Why is there separate need for Mac Address?

Tags: networking, mac-address

I know that router assign private ip address to devices that are connected to it wirelessly. Then, why is there need of Mac Address since devices can be distinguished by private ip assigned to them.
Or Mac Address is used to distinguish type of device whether it is mobile,pc or other device.

Comment: "_I know that router assign private ip address to devices that are connected to it wirelessly._" No, DHCP servers can assign IP addresses to hosts configured for DHCP. Routers route packets between networks MAC addressing is used by _some_ (the IEEE) layer-2 protocols to deliver layer-2 frames on the same layer-2 domain. The layer-2 protocols can carry any layer-3 (network) protocols, so that you can use IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc. on the same layer-2 devices. For example, the transition from IPX to IPv4, and now to IPv6, can use all the same layer-2 network infrastructure.

Answer (score -1):

MAC address is used for physical network cards .
For a Router to assign an ip address for a pc or a phone , it needs its MAC address .
the router then  will have a CAM table in it ( MAC addresses table ) : it will be like this 
MAC              |IP
AAAA:BBBB:CC00   | 192.168.1.22
AAAA:BBBB:CC11   | 192.168.1.23
AAAA:BBBB:CC22   | 192.168.1.24

more about why is MAC addresses used here : 
https://people.richland.edu/dkirby/141macaddress.htm

Comment: Switches (layer-2 devices for protocols that use MAC addresses) have CAM tables, routers (and other layer-3 devices) have ARP tables. There is a big difference. The switch CAM table relates the MAC address to the switch interface, but ARP relates the IP address to the MAC address.